# Android: AudioRecord.read() return array filled with "0" after phone call

Tags: android, phone-call, audiorecord

I am writing a program to record and play sound real time. It work well but after I make a phone call and end the phone call, the program play about 1 second and then it silent without error.
I bug to check value and see audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffer.leng) return array filled with zero value.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Your phone took control of the microphone and blocked audio record from it. To check and see if this happens `Log` the value returned by `read()`

```
while(recording) {

    int resultOfRead = audioRecord.read(anArray, 0, anArray.length);
    Log.d("MY_TAG", "Read result: " + resultOfRead);

    if(resultOfRead < 0) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100, 0);
            audioRecord.startRecording(); // restart audio recording
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception", e); // Error trying to sleep thread
        }
    }
}
```